# gtk-2.0 theme: is it possible to change inactive slider?

Tags: gtk

I'm doing some slight modification of an existing theme, and I want to have the sliders be different colors in active and inactive windows.
Here is an example of the slider code in the gtkrc file

```
image {
  function          = SLIDER
  recolorable       = TRUE
  state             = NORMAL
  file              = "slider.png"
  border            = { 2, 2, 2, 2 }
  stretch           = TRUE
  orientation       = VERTICAL
}
```

The option "state" seems to have only 3 choices: NORMAL, PRELIGHT, and INSENSITIVE
There doesn't seem to be an "INACTIVE" which is what I need. I want to set the image file for sliders on an inactive window to something different.

Answer (score 1):

The inactive state is the NORMAL state. From the Python [gtk docs](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkstyle.html)

> A `gtk.Style` holds information for the five possible widget states
>   though not every widget supports all five states:
>
> `gtk.STATE_NORMAL`    The state of a sensitive widget that is not active
>   and does not have the focus
>
> `gtk.STATE_ACTIVE`    The state of a sensitive widget when it is active
>   e.g. a button that is pressed but not yet released
>
> `gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT`  The state of a sensitive widget that has the focus
>   e.g. a button that has the mouse pointer over it.
>
> `gtk.STATE_SELECTED`  The state of a widget that is selected e.g.
>   selected text in a gtk.Entry widget
>
> `gtk.STATE_INSENSITIVE`   The state of a widget that is insensitive and
>   will not respond to any events e.g. cannot be activated, selected or
>   prelit.

I've done some GTK2 programming in Python over the last few years, but I'm certainly not an expert in all of its intricacies. And I haven't played around much with themes. I'm not sure if what you want to do *can* be done, but hopefully someone with more expertise will be able to make a definitive statement in this regard.

FWIW, I *do* know how to make a slider in an GTK application change color depending on whether the main window currently has focus or not, but I guess that's not much use to you. But if you want to play around with it, let me know & I'll paste my Python code into this answer.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I think I'll just try to make the theme work with a constant slider color